# Extract data from XML in TSQL (Sql Server 2016)

Tags: regex, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I am trying to come up with a way to get rid of XML structs, and get all the variables out of there, as well as their associated values. I want to eventually place such items in a real (not temp) table. I have a stored proc as well as a function to do this, but it is not working. I am really unsure what the reason is and how to make the regex's work to extract just the variable names and the values in string that belong to them. Do you guys see what is wrong? I looked this up in Stack and yet I am still stuck. The  raw XML string I need to extract data from is the following:

```
<var name='ENDA6012E0891_1'><string>N</string></var><var name='SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1'><string>Y</string></var><var name='HOMEVACANT_1'><string>N</string></var>
```

The stored proc is as follows:

```
    USE [InternalPortal]
    GO
            /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OldSysDataConv]    Script Date: 3/2/2020 4:57:41 PM ******/
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OldSysDataConv]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @MinID int
        DECLARE @MaxID int
        DECLARE @COUNTER int
        DECLARE @ROW int

        DECLARE @NewXML VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @NewXMLWddxRem VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @NewXMLWddxRem2 VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @CurrXML VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @TempDataConv TABLE (
DecIter int not null Identity Primary Key,
        DecPageID smallint,
        PolicyID int,
DecInfo text
    )
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        INSERT @TempDataConv
        SELECT
                    DecPageID,
                    PolicyID,
                    DecInfo
        FROM [InternalPortal].[dbo].[Decpages]



        SET @MinID = 1
        SELECT @MaxID = MAX(DecIter) FROM @TempDataConv
        --PRINT '@MaxID'
        --PRINT @MaxID

        SELECT DecInfo FROM @TempDataConv
        WHILE @MinID <= @MaxID
        BEGIN
                    select @CurrXML = DecInfo from @TempDataConv where DecIter = @MinID
                    --select * from InternalPortal.dbo.SplitStrings_XML_udf(@CurrXML,'>')
                    set @NewXML = REPLACE(@CurrXML, '<wddxPacket version=''1.0''><header/><data><struct>', '')
                    set @NewXMLWddxRem = REPLACE(@NewXML, '<wddxPacket version=''1.0''><header></header><data><struct>', '')
                    --set @NewXMLWddxRem2 = REPLACE(@NewXMLWddxRem, '^[<var name='']', '')

                    update @TempDataConv set DecInfo = @NewXMLWddxRem where DecIter =  @MinID
                    --select @NewXMLWddxRem = DecInfo from @TempDataConv where DecIter = @MinID
                    set @NewXMLWddxRem2 = InternalPortal.dbo.RepetitiveReplace(@NewXMLWddxRem, '^[<var name='']', '', 11)
                    print @NewXMLWddxRem2
                    set @MinID = @MinID + 1
        END
        select DecInfo from @TempDataConv
    END
```

And the function that is called yet does not work is as follows:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RepetitiveReplace
    (
     @P_String VARCHAR(MAX),
     @P_Pattern VARCHAR(MAX),
     @P_ReplaceString VARCHAR(MAX),
     @P_ReplaceLength INT = 1
     )
         RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
         BEGIN
              DECLARE @Index INT;

              -- Get starting point of pattern
              SET @Index = PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String);

              while @Index > 0
              begin
                       --replace matching charactger at index
                       SET @P_String = STUFF(@P_String, PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String), @P_ReplaceLength, @P_ReplaceString);
                       SET @Index = PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String);
              end

              RETURN @P_String;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question I get, that the XML you provide is already "cleaned" in a way... It would help, if you provided an example of your real XML (reduced...). I'm pretty sure, that nothing of the above is needed acutally.

With the XML provided I would use the following query:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<var name="ENDA6012E0891_1">
  <string>N</string>
</var>
<var name="SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1">
  <string>Y</string>
</var>
<var name="HOMEVACANT_1">
  <string>N</string>
</var>';
```

--The query

```sql
select varElement.value('@name','varchar(100)') AS VarName
      ,varElement.value('(string/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS VarValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/var') A(varElement);
```

The idea in short:

- We use `.nodes()` to retrieve each `<var>` element as a derived set.
- We use `.value()` to read the attributes content, which returns the variable's name.
- We use `.value()` again, but apply a **relativ XPath** (no leading `/`) below the current `<var>` element.

If the values might use different types (e.g. `<int>` instead of `<string>`) you can use

```
      ,varElement.value('(*/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS VarValue
```

This will read the first element's content below `<var>`.

Comment: Provided the data in the post. I assume that what you are looking for with what you requested is verification that this in proper XML. Yes, it is. Some of it is sensitive data (not all of it), thus why I did not post the entire thing.  

When I run the query, I get the error:   Must declare the scalar variable "@TempDataConv".


Here is what I am running:  
  
         `select DecInfo.value('@name','varchar(100)') AS VarName,  
         DecInfo.value('(string/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS VarValue  
         FROM @TempDataConv.nodes('/var') A(varElement);`

Comment: @Noone, I'm using a declare variable `@xml`. The variable `@TempDataConv` is coming from your side. You must find out what is missing...

Comment: I already declared the table, which is @TempDataConv. Hence, the question. Please refer to original code. It actually has a different problem here than the var not being declared..

Comment: @Noone, If `@TempDataConv` is a table variable you must use `FROM @TempDataConv tdc CROSS APPLY tdc.nodes('/var') A(varElement);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by, "variables" you are referring to XML attributes and that you are attempting to retrieve the attribute name and value. Using your sample data you can do so like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
<var name="ENDA6012E0891_1"><string>N</string></var><var name="SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1"><string>Y</string></var><var name="HOMEVACANT_1"><string>N</string></var>';

SELECT 
  AttribName  = a.Attrib.value('local-name(.)','varchar(8000)'),
  AttribValue = a.Attrib.value('.','varchar(8000)')
FROM   @XML.nodes('//@*') AS a(Attrib);
```

**Returns:**

```
AttribName  AttribValue
----------- -------------------
name        ENDA6012E0891_1
name        SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1
name        HOMEVACANT_1
```

Against a table you could do this:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (SomeId INT IDENTITY, SomeXML XML);
INSERT @t(SomeXML)
VALUES('<var name="ENDA6012E0891_1"></var><var name="SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1"></var><var name="HOMEVACANT_1"></var>'),
('<var dog="Blood Hound"></var><var cat="Orange One"></var><var creature="Dragon"></var><xxx color="pink"/>');

-- Solution
SELECT
  SomeId      = t.SomeId,
  AttribName  = a.Attrib.value('local-name(.)','varchar(8000)'),
  AttribValue = a.Attrib.value('.','varchar(8000)')
FROM        @t AS t
CROSS APPLY t.SomeXML.nodes('//@*') AS a(Attrib);
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId      AttribName  AttribValue
----------- ----------- -------------------
1           name        ENDA6012E0891_1
1           name        SAFETYRAILSTEPS_1
1           name        HOMEVACANT_1
2           dog         Blood Hound
2           cat         Orange One
2           creature    Dragon
2           color       pink
```

On a side note: Your repetitiveReplace function (or Regex) is not the tool for this kind of this - using SQL Server's native SQL-XML support is the easiest and most efficient solution. That said, I recently created a similar function that does the same thing but is a bit more powerful. I wrote it as a T-SQL tail recursive [Higher Order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) Normally I'm not a fan of scalar UDFs but this guy performs nicely as a scalar inline function if you have SQL Server 2019. Note that it's only 3 lines of code.

**PowerStuff32:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PowerStuff32
(
  @String VARCHAR(8000),
  @Seek   VARCHAR(100),
  @StLen  TINYINT,
  @StWith VARCHAR(10)
)
/****************************************************************************************
Written by Alan Burstein 20200304

Note: This is a beta version of this function. It's a recursive scalar UDF and will error
out on 32 iterations. Add a counter for protection.

Note this example:
  DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1000) = 
    'Call me at 555-2233, 555 3344 or 1.800.555.6678 about case number 00234. Thanks!';

  SELECT f1.Txt 
  FROM   (VALUES(dbo.PowerStuff32(@string,
           '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',8,'<REMOVED>'))) AS f1(Txt);
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT AS BEGIN RETURN 
(
  SELECT      CHOOSE(st.C, @String, dbo.PowerStuff32(st.Txt,@Seek,@StLen,@StWith))
  FROM        (VALUES(PATINDEX(@Seek,@String)))                           AS nxt(D)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(@String,nxt.D,@StLen,@StWith),SIGN(nxt.D)+1)) AS st(Txt,C)
);
END;
```

Example (Replace phone numbers with the text "Removed"):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1000) = 
  'Call me at 555-2233, 555 3344 or 1.800.555.6678 about case number 00234. Thanks!';

SELECT f1.Txt 
FROM   (VALUES(dbo.PowerStuff32(@string,
         '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',8,'{REMOVED}'))) AS f1(Txt);
```

**Returns:**

> > > > Call me at {REMOVED}, {REMOVED} or 1.800.{REMOVED} about case number 00234. Thanks!

Comment: Your approach might work in this case, but it seems to be rather dangerous to start with each and any attribute  (`//@*`) anywhere in the XML and rely on a XPath `'.'` to return nothing else than the one and only value. I can imagine a lot of situations where this might return a lot but not what you expect...

Comment: It appears that is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Well, my magic crystall ball is out for cleaning :-) May be you are right...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that query part did help quite a bit. I do not get any results appearing under AttribName, but do get the values in AttribValue. Is local-name(.) supposed to be the name of the "column" in the XML? How might this work with the proper name, which is "var name?" I am in need of both in order to execute this to extract named columns and values, and then add to a table. This is an old data format the company used in the past, and the point of this project is to convert it all and add to a table, thus the need for both the "column" name and the associated value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as follows. And yep, that very old data is formatted as WDDX in the records, but I was simply getting rid of the WDDX values in order to deal with this more simply.. I thought I would be able to simply reference the variables without that..

```
    SELECT  x.v.value('@name[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS VarName,
    x.v.value('local-name((./*)[1])', 'VARCHAR(255)') as VarType,
    x.v.value('.','VARCHAR(255)') AS Value
    FROM @TempDataConv
    CROSS APPLY DecInfo.nodes('/wddxPacket/data/struct/var') AS x(v)
```